# Objective-C : Properties question

Tags: objective-c, properties

As far as I understand when you use properties the compiler still converts them to accessor methods during compilation. I got a little irritated when I read you need OSX 10.5 or later to use properties. Why is that so?

If in the compiled application are in fact still accessor methods I see no need for OSX 10.5. Or is there something else going on during run-time?

Comment: I imagine that OS X 10.5 added more functionality than just properties.

Answer (score 3):

Because the Objective-C 2.0 runtime was not back ported to 10.4. You need compiler and runtime support to handle all of ObjC 2.0 properly.

Comment: Yes, for instance, atomic properties use a lightweight locking mechanism which is not available in the older runtime.